# Plotting Minkowski product of two sets in complex 2D plane

Tags: graphics, complex

I am trying to draw Minkowski product of two sets in complex 2D
plane in `Mathematica`. While I can draw the individual complex 2d plane for these sets
in Mathematica using `ComplexRegionPlot`, I do not know if there is
a way to draw the corresponding Minkowski product.

For example, consider the following complex 2d regions
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{G}_{1} & =\left\{ z\in\mathbf{C}\mid\mathrm{Re}(z)\geq\vert z\vert^{2}\right\} ,\\
\mathcal{G}_{2} & =\left\{ z\in\mathbf{C}\mid\frac{3}{2}\mathrm{Re}(z)\geq\vert z\vert^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right\} ,
\end{align*}

where their Minkowski product is

$$
\mathcal{G}_{1}\cdot\mathcal{G}_{2}=\left\{ z_{1}z_{2} \in \mathbf{C} \mid z_{1}\in\mathcal{G}_{1},z_{2}\in\mathcal{G}_{2}\right\} ,
$$

and I am trying to plot the complex region associated with this Minkowski
product $\mathcal{G}_{1}\cdot\mathcal{G}_{2}$. Any help/suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can not plot a 4 dimensional region in 3 dimensions. The best you can due is draw slices and use color for an additional dimension.

Comment: @DanielHuber: The Minkowski product is a subset of the complex plane. See [Russian version of Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сумма_Минковского) to this end.

Comment: @DanielHuber, thanks for your comment. However, user64494 is indeed right in this case, the Minkowski product will lie in the complex plane because we are constructing the points in the new set $\mathcal{G}_1 \cdot \mathcal{G}_2$ by pointwise multiplication of the elements of the sets $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$, and such points will also be complex numbers lying in the complex plane.

Comment: @user64494 There is a difference between Minkowski sum and Minkowski product. As I understand it, the "sum" is the sum of all  elements of the two sets. However, the product is the set of all ordered pairs with elements of the two sets. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @DanielHuber: The Mincowsky product  $\mathcal{G}_{1}\mathcal{G}_{}$ is the set $\{zw: z\in \mathcal{G}_{1},w \in \mathcal{G}_{2}\}\subset \mathbb{C}.$  This is a standard definition in group theory. Also look in Russian edition of Wiki and the cited article.

Comment: @user64494  Thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done as follows. First, we switch to the reals. Second, we write down the definition of the Minkowski product for the specified case by ($z=x+iy\in \mathcal{G}_{1},\,w=s+it\in \mathcal{G}_{2},\,zw=xs-yt+i(xt+ys)$)

```
Exists[{x, y, s, t},a == x*s - y*t&& b == x*t + y*s&& x >= x^2 + y^2 &&3/2*s >= s^2 + t^2 + 1/2];
```

Then we find the conditions on $a,b$ by

```
r = Resolve[Exists[{x, y, s, t},a == x*s - y*t && b == x*t + y*s && x >= x^2 + y^2 && 
3/2*s >= s^2 + t^2 + 1/2], Reals];
```

At last, we draw the product by

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[r, {a, b}]]
```

[image]

Comment: user64494, thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: in your code, `r` , the third region, `RegionPlot[(b^2 <= 1/64 && -3 a + 4 a^2 - 4 b^2 <= 0), {a, -1, 
  1}, {b, -1, 1}]` is also a rectangle-like region.

Comment: @cvgmt: You are right. In fact, you obtain the same region, but on a longer  and more complicated way. +1 for your answer.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks! Since I want to do more general situation. Now I am trying to  consider another method to avoid solve the equations.

Answer (score 3):

First we transform the complex to real.

```
expr1 = Block[{z = x + I*y}, (Re[z] >= Abs[z]^2 // ComplexExpand)]
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[expr1, {x, y}]
expr2 = Block[{w = u + I*v}, (3/2 Re[w] >= Abs[w]^2 + 1/2 // 
     ComplexExpand)];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[expr2, {u, v}]
expr = Thread[{p,q} == ((x + I*y) (u + I*v) // ReIm // ComplexExpand)]
```

the results are

```
x >= x^2 + y^2
ImplicitRegion[x >= x^2 + y^2, {x, y}]
(3 u)/2 >= 1/2 + u^2 + v^2
ImplicitRegion[(3 u)/2 >= 1/2 + u^2 + v^2, {u, v}]
{p == u x - v y, q == v x + u y}
```

and then we construct a Cartesian Procuct of the two region `reg1` and `reg2`

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   x >= x^2 + y^2 && (3 u)/2 >= 1/2 + u^2 + v^2, {x, y, u, v}];
```

and Map the `reg` according the `(p == u x - v y && q == v x + u y)`

That is

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   x >= x^2 + y^2 && (3 u)/2 >= 1/2 + u^2 + v^2, {x, y, u, v}];
sol = Resolve[
  Exists[{x, y, u, v}, 
   Element[{x, y, u, v}, reg], (p == u x - v y && q == v x + u y)], 
  Reals]
RegionPlot[List @@ sol // Evaluate, {p, -1, 1}, {q, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but Minkowski product is not a Cartesian product (see https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1014737602641 ). This is not it though you are on the right way.

Comment: @user64494  Here we use Cartesian Product to construct  Minkowski product , just as your approach.

Comment: cvgmt (@ does not work), The Minkowski product under consideration is a subset of the comlex plane, not a list of domains.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, it is the union of the list of domains. Since I want to display the method,so  I use `List @@ sol ` instead of `sol`

Comment: cvgmt (@ does not work): Your claim 'Yes, it is the union of the list of domains" is ungrounded.

Comment: @user64494  in your  code,`r` is also the union of  some regions, just the same.

Comment: cvgmt (@ does not work): Your claim "just the same" is false. In particular, there is no rectangle in`r`. Your claim 'Yes, it is the union of the list of domains" is still ungrounded.

Comment: `ParametricRegion[{{u x - v y, v x + u y}, (3 u)/2 >= 1/2 + u^2 + v^2 &&  x >= x^2 + y^2}, {x, y,u, v}]//Region`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how robust it is, but you could try using [`ParametricRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion). For example:

```
R = ParametricRegion[
    {
    {x u - y v, x v + y u}, (* Re/Im parts the product *)
    {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[x > x^2 + y^2, {x, y}] &&
    {u, v} ∈ ImplicitRegion[3/2 x > x^2 + y^2 + 1/2, {x, y}]
    },
    {x, y, u, v}
]
```

> ParametricRegion[{{x u - y v,
> y u + x v}, {x, y} ∈
> ImplicitRegion[x > x^2 + y^2, {x, y}] && {u, v} ∈
> ImplicitRegion[(3 x)/2 > 1/2 + x^2 + y^2, {x, y}]}, {x, y, u, v}]

Discretizing the region:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[R]
```

[warning snipped]

[image]

This can be made into a function. Define a wrapper representing a complex region `ComplexRegion`, and define a function that converts this into an [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion):

```
convertToImplicitRegion[ComplexRegion[bool_, z_Symbol]] := Module[
    {x = Unique[], y = Unique[]},

    ImplicitRegion[
        ComplexExpand[bool /. z -> x + I y],
        {x, y}
    ]
]

convertToImplicitRegion[reg_] := If[RegionQ[reg],
    reg,
    $Failed
]
```

Then, define a function that creates the [`ParametricRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion) and discretizes it:

```
Options[MinkowskiProduct] = Options[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion];

MinkowskiProduct[c1_, c2_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
    {i1, i2, x, y, u, v},
    
    i1 = convertToImplicitRegion[c1];
    i2 = convertToImplicitRegion[c2]; 
    Quiet[
        BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
            ParametricRegion[
                {
                    {x u - y v, x v + y u},
                    {x,y} ∈ i1 && {u,v} ∈ i2
                },
                {x, y, u, v}
            ],
            opts
        ],
        BoundaryDiscretizeRegion::brepl
    ] /; !MemberQ[{i1, i2}, $Failed]
]
```

Your example again:

```
MinkowskiProduct[
    ComplexRegion[Re[z] > Abs[z]^2, z], 
    ComplexRegion[3/2 Re[z] > Abs[z]^2 + 1/2, z],
    Axes -> True
]
```

[image]

And another example:

```
MinkowskiProduct[
    ComplexRegion[Re[z] > Abs[z]^2, z], 
    ComplexRegion[0 < Re[z] < 1 && 0 < Im[z] < 1, z],
    Axes -> True
]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, `Region[ParametricRegion[{{x u - y v, x v + y u},{x, y} \[Element] 
     ImplicitRegion[x > x^2 + y^2, {x, y}] && {u, v} \[Element] 
     ImplicitRegion[3/2 x > x^2 + y^2 + 1/2, {x, y}]}, {x, y, u, v}]]` fails, so you need in discretization.

Comment: In any case, this is a direct and natural approach, so +1.

Comment: I'd like to quote [the linked article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1014737602641): " In certain applications, the availability of exact Minkowski products is a useful alternative to the naive bounding approximations that are customarily employed in "complex circular arithmetic".

Comment: Your another example can be done analytically by splitting cases, e.g. `Exists[{x, y, s, t}, 
 a == x*s - y*t && b == x*t + y*s && x >= x^2 + y^2 && t <= 1 && 
  s == 0 && t >= 0]` and so on.