# Efficiently compute Minkowski sum of a 2D Region and a Disc of radius r?

Tags: computational-geometry, polygons

Given a 2D *Mathematica* [Region](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region.html?q=Region), e.g. `A = Region[RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{2, 0}, 1]]]`, how can I grow the region by an arbitrary radius *r*?
For example, automatically compute the region outlined in black for *r* = 1/2 in

```
Show[A, Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 2.5, {.55, 5.8}],
   Circle[{2, 0}, .5, {1.72, 4.5}],
   Circle[{1.75, .98}, .5, {5, 7}],
   Circle[{1.75, -.98}, .5, {5.9, 7.55}],
   Red, Point[{1.73, .98}]}]]
```

[image: Outline of a region grown by a radius of 1/2.]

In [CGAL](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Minkowski_sum_2/index.html), the operation of computing the Minkowski sum P⊕B<sub>*r*</sub> of a polygon P with a disc B<sub>*r*</sub> of radius *r* centered at the origin is widely known as offsetting the polygon P by a radius *r*.

A typical example is
[image: convex polygon] or [image].

I'd like to end with a Region because of the many built-in functions that *Mathematica* provides. This is similar to [Dilation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dilation.html) of a BinaryImage, but for my purposes a Region is better than a BinaryImage. This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628321/polygon-equal-edge-offsetting) suggested trying [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php), but I'd like to remain in Mathematica.

Comment: related: [How can I enclose a closed curve with another identical slightly bigger closed curve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/228527/125)

Comment: ... and [How can I sketch a right-angled triangle?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235414/125)

Answer (score 5):

OP and reply the comment.

```
reg1 = Disk[{0, 0}, 1/2]; 
reg2 = 
 ImplicitRegion[u^2 + v^2 <= 4 && 3 + u^2 + v^2 >= 4 u, {u, v}];
 sol =
  Resolve[Exists[{x, y, u, v}, 
   Element[{x, y}, reg1] && 
    Element[{u, v}, reg2], (p == x + u && q == y + v)], 
  Reals]; RegionPlot[List @@ sol, {p, -4, 4}, {q, -4, 4}, 
 PlotPoints -> 80, BoundaryStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

```
reg1 = Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 2}]; 
reg2 = 
 ImplicitRegion[u^2 + v^2 <= 4 && 3 + u^2 + v^2 >= 4 u, {u, v}]; 
sol =
  Resolve[Exists[{x, y, u, v}, 
   Element[{x, y}, reg1] && 
    Element[{u, v}, reg2], (p == x + u && q == y + v)], Reals];
RegionPlot[List @@ sol, {p, -8, 8}, {q, -8, 8}, PlotPoints -> 80, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

**Edit**

For two  simple regions some times it work. (for example elliptical disk and rectangle)

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{{x, y} + {u, v}, {x, y} ∈ 
      Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 2}] && Abs[u] + Abs[v] <= 1}, {x, y, u, v}];
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[reg], BoundaryStyle -> Green, 
 PlotStyle -> Gray, Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
reg1 = Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 2}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[Abs[u] + Abs[v] <= 1, {u, v}];
sol = Resolve[
  Exists[{x, y, u, v}, 
   Element[{x, y}, reg1] && 
    Element[{u, v}, reg2], (p == x + u && q == y + v)], Reals]
RegionPlot[List @@ sol // Evaluate, {p, -4, 4}, {q, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

**Original**

A simple example.

```
ParametricRegion[{{x, y} + {u, v}, 
   x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && Abs[u] + Abs[v] <= 1}, {x, y, u, v}] // Region
```

[image]

Or

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && Abs[u] + Abs[v] <= 1, {x, y, u, v}];
sol = Resolve[
  Exists[{x, y, u, v}, 
   Element[{x, y, u, v}, reg], (p == x + u && q == y + v)], Reals]
RegionPlot[List @@ sol // Evaluate, {p, -2, 2}, {q, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

For simple region, we can also use

```
reg = Circle[{0, 0}, 3];
d = SignedRegionDistance[reg, {x, y}];
Show[RegionPlot[d <= 1, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}], Graphics[reg]]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when replacing `Abs[u] + Abs[v] <= 1` with membership in an arbitrary region, such as `RegionMember[A, {u, v}]`, unfortunately...any idea why?

Comment: cvgmt uses [my idea](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/233264/plotting-minkowski-product-of-two-sets-in-complex-2d-plane/233274#233274) without any reference.

Comment: @cvgmt: In any case, that reference should be done.

Comment: @user64494 In the above link, please note that I have post the answer before you post your answer. So it is just my idea, not your idea.

Comment: @cvgmt: The difference in time equals 9 minutes.

Comment: `reg1 = Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 2}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[
   u^2 + v^2 <= 4 && 3 + u^2 + v^2 >= 4 u, {u, v}];
sol = Resolve[
  Exists[{x, y, u, v}, 
   Element[{x, y}, reg1] && 
    Element[{u, v}, reg2], (p == x + u && q == y + v)], Reals]
RegionPlot[List @@ sol // Evaluate, {p, -8, 8}, {q, -8, 8}]`

Comment: `reg1 = Disk[{0, 0}, 1/2];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[
   u^2 + v^2 <= 4 && 3 + u^2 + v^2 >= 4 u, {u, v}];
sol = Resolve[
  Exists[{x, y, u, v}, 
   Element[{x, y}, reg1] && 
    Element[{u, v}, reg2], (p == x + u && q == y + v)], Reals]
RegionPlot[List @@ sol // Evaluate, {p, -4, 4}, {q, -4, 4}, 
 PlotPoints -> 80]`

Comment: @cvgmt: What do you want to say in your latest comment? The code `eg1 = Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 2}]; reg2 = ImplicitRegion[    u^2 + v^2 <= 4 && 3 + u^2 + v^2 >= 4 u, {u, v}]; sol = Resolve[   Exists[{x, y, u, v},     Element[{x, y}, reg1] &&      Element[{u, v}, reg2], (p == x + u && q == y + v)], Reals] RegionPlot[List @@ sol // Evaluate, {p, -8, 8}, {q, -8, 8}]` produces an empty plot and a big output. A good code is a commented code. If you read my answer, maybe, you will understand the deficiency of our approaches with `Resolve`.

Comment: +1. Now your code at the top works.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to decompose your region into a collection of convex regions, find the Minkowski sum of each, then union the result.

The [Minkowski sum of two convex polygonal regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition#Convex_hulls_of_Minkowski_sums) is a call to [`ConvexHullMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html) after replacing each vertex of one region with all offset vertices of the other.

```
A = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{2, 0}, 1]]];
cpts = CirclePoints[0.5, 100];

decompcoords = PolygonCoordinates /@ PolygonDecomposition[A, "Convex"];

offsetcoords = Table[Join @@ Outer[Plus, dc, cpts, 1], {dc, decompcoords}];

RegionUnion @@ ConvexHullMesh /@ offsetcoords
```

[image]

Comment: A good code is a commented code. Your `& /@ #))& /@ decompcoords;` as well as other pieces of your code are not understable for me. Such type answers do not make a good impression and are useless for an average Mathematica user.

Answer (score 2):

Minkovski sum is not substantial here. In fact, the $\frac 1 2$-[neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)) of `RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{2, 0}, 1]]` is required. Following the documentation, this can be done as follows. First, we define

```
d = RegionDistance[DiscretizeRegion[RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{2, 0}, 1]]], {x, y}];
```

The above does not work without `DiscretizeRegion` for me.

Then,

```
RegionPlot[d <= 1/2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Addition. I'd like to explain why the similar approaches from [that  post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/233264/plotting-minkowski-product-of-two-sets-in-complex-2d-plane/233274#233274) do not work here.
We start from

```
RegionMember[RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{2, 0}, 1]], {x, y}]
```

> `(x | y) \[Element] Reals && x^2 + y^2 <= 4 && 3 + x^2 + y^2 > 4 x`

Next,

```
r = 1/2; ms = Resolve[Exists[{x, y, s, t}, a == x + s && b == y + t && 
x^2 + y^2 <= 4 &&  3 + x^2 + y^2 > 4 x && (s - x)^2 + (t - y)^2 <= r^2], Reals];
LeafCount[ms]
```

> `99435`

We see `ms` is too complicated and big  to work with. This also explains the necessity of `DiscretizeRegion` in the above.