# Integrating a function over a region defined as the epsilon-neighborhood of a triangle

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions, geometry

I would like to integrate the function f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 over the epsilon-neighborhood of the triangle {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}. By epsilon-neighborhood, I mean the set of points which are closer to the triangle than epsilon (let's say epsilon = 0.5).

I do not know what is the best way to **define such a region**, how to **plot it** and how to **integrate** a function over it.
I have tried the following code, but it gives back the incorrect result 0.3 even for the area (I don't know why). It seems that the same code works correctly for a Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], somehow.

```
RegT = Region[Triangle[{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}]]

(* Define the epsilon-neighborhood of a triangle *)
epsilon=0.5;
RegTneigh = ImplicitRegion[Norm[RegionNearest[RegT, {x, y}] - {x, y}, 2] <= epsilon, {x, y}]

(* Plotting the region (I don't know how to simply plot RegTneigh) *)
RegionPlot[Norm[RegionNearest[RegT, {x, y}] - {x, y}, 2] <= 0.5, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 2}, ImagePadding -> 30, PlotPoints -> 30]
        
(* Checking the area of the region using f(x,y) = 1 *)            
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] RegTneigh]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic word you are searching is: "RegionDilation". With this, your calculation looks like:

```
epsilon = 0.5;
region = 
  RegionDilation[Triangle[{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}], epsilon];
RegionPlot[region]

(*Checking the area of the region using f(x,y)=1*)
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] region]
(*Doing the integral of f[x,y]*)
f[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2;
NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] region]
```

[image]

Comment: For information, RegionDilation was introduced in version 12.3

Answer (score 3):

For  Mathematica `versions  <13` try

```
eps=0.5
dreieck = Triangle[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]
\[CapitalDelta]eps =ImplicitRegion[RegionDistance[dreieck, {x, y}] <= eps, {x, y}]

Area[\[CapitalDelta]eps] (*4.19961*)
NIntegrate[1,Element[{x,y},\[CapitalDelta]eps]] (*4.19961*)
NIntegrate[x^2+y^2,Element[{x,y},\[CapitalDelta]eps]] (*3.5966*)
```

Comment: Thanks, with dreieck = Triangle[{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}] works fine!

Comment: @Zsombor Sorry, cut & paste error, I corrected my answer

Answer (score 3):

- Here we even does not depend on `RegionDistance` or `RegionNearest`,see my privious answer. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/244568/72111
- a point `{x,y}` belong to such dilation region iff there exists `{p, q} ∈ triangle` and
  `{u, v} ∈ disk` such that `{x,  y} == {p, q} + {u, v}`

```
Clear["Global`*"];
epsilon=1/2;
disk = Disk[{0, 0},epsilon];
triangle = Triangle[{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}];
sol = Resolve[
   Exists[{p, q, u, 
     v}, {p, q} ∈ triangle && {u, v} ∈ disk, {x, 
      y} == {p, q} + {u, v}], Reals];
reg = ImplicitRegion[sol, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[reg, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {Green, triangle}]
reg // Area
Integrate[1, {x, y} ∈ reg]
Integrate[x^2+y^2, {x, y} ∈ reg]
```

[image]

> `1/4 (8 + 4 Sqrt[2] + π)`

> `1/4 (8 + 4 Sqrt[2] + π)`

> `1/96 (136 + 88 Sqrt[2] + 27 π)`