# Numeric integration and RegionDilation in higher dimensions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, regions, simplex, convexhull

I would like to integrate over a **dilationed** region in higher dimensions.

In **3 dimensions** it works well.

```
(*Nintegrate over a 3 dim region*)
regS = Simplex[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 
     1}, {-(1/3), -(1/3), -(1/3)}}];
regSdil = RegionDilation[regS, 0.1];
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] regS]  (*0.333*)
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] regSe] (*0.764*)
```

But in **4 dimensions** I got the following **error message**: "Invalid integration variable or limit(s)"

```
(*Nintegrate over a 4 dim region*)
regS = Simplex[{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
     1}, {1/4 (1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/4 (1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/4 (1 - Sqrt[5]), 
     1/4 (1 - Sqrt[5])}}];
regSdil = RegionDilation[regS, 0.1];
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z, k} \[Element] regS]  (*0.0931*) 
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z, k} \[Element] 
  regSdil] (***"Invalid integration variable or limit(s)"***)
```

I don't know why. Is there a way to solve this. Or is there a better way to do such a calculation?

Comment: The problem is with RegionDilation, not the integration. If you evaluate RegionQ[regSdil], you'll get False. So RegionDilation does not produce a 4-dimensional region. It works in simpler 4D cases, e.g., RegionDilation[Ball[{0,0,0,0}],0.1] gives a larger 4D ball.

Answer (score 6):

- `RegionDilation` seems only work for simple region in higher dimensions.

```
RegionDilation[Ball[{0, 0, 0, 0}, 1], .1]
RegionDilation[Ball[{0, 0, 0, 0}, 1], Ball[{0, 0, 0, 0}, .1]]
```

> `Ball[{0, 0, 0, 0}, 1.1]`

- We try to add sphere points around the 5 points of the simplex `regS` and construct a `ConvexHullRegion` and integrate on such dilation region of `regS`.
- Version 13.3.1, Version 14.0.0

```
Clear["Global`*"];
regS = Simplex[{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
     1}, {1/4   (1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/4   (1 - Sqrt[5]), 
     1/4   (1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/4   (1 - Sqrt[5])}}];
pts = regS[[1]];
r = .1;
regdilation = 
  ConvexHullRegion[
   Flatten[Outer[Plus, pts, RandomPoint[Sphere[{0, 0, 0, 0}, r], 200],
      1], 1]];
ineqs = First@regdilation /. 
   Thread[{Indexed[\[FormalX], {1}], Indexed[\[FormalX], {2}], 
      Indexed[\[FormalX], {3}], Indexed[\[FormalX], {4}]} -> {x, y, z,
       w}];
NIntegrate[
 Boole[ineqs], {x, y, z, w} ∈ 
  Cuboid @@ 
   Transpose[{First@# - 2 r, Last@# +2 r} & /@ RegionBounds[regS]]]
```

> `0.264839`.

- Version 11.3 , Version 12.2

```
Clear["Global`*"];
regS = Simplex[{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
     1}, {1/4   (1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/4   (1 - Sqrt[5]), 
     1/4   (1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/4   (1 - Sqrt[5])}}];
r = .1;
{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}, {z1, z2}, {w1, 
    w2}} = {First@# - 2 r, Last@# + 2 r} & /@ RegionBounds[regS];
NIntegrate[
 Boole[RegionDistance[regS, {x, y, z, w}] <= r], {x, x1, x2}, {y, y1, 
  y2}, {z, z1, z2}, {w, w1, w2}]
```

> `0.277332`.

Comment: It is a pity that this [Integrating a function over a region defined as the epsilon-neighborhood of a triangle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296587/integrating-a-function-over-a-region-defined-as-the-epsilon-neighborhood-of-a-tr/296600#296600)  cannot be generalized in this case! Any idea why?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  I found that  the`RegionDistance` approach work in 11.3 and 12.2 but not in 14.0 version.

Comment: Thanks! I tried `ball4D = ImplicitRegion[
  u1^2 + u2^2 + u3^2 + u4^2 <= .1, {u1, u2, u3, u4}]
regS = Simplex[{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
     1}, {1/4 (1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/4 (1 - Sqrt[5]), 1/4 (1 - Sqrt[5]), 
     1/4 (1 - Sqrt[5])}}];
pts = regS[[1]]  
sol = Resolve[
  Exists[{v1, v2, v3, v4, u1, u2, u3, 
    u4}, {v1, v2, v3, v4} \[Element] 
     regS && {u1, u2, u3, u4} \[Element] ball4D, {x1, x2, x3, 
     x4} == {v1, v2, v3, v4} + {u1, u2, u3, u4}] , Reals] 
reg = ImplicitRegion[sol, {x1, x2, x3, x4}];` without success

Comment: Thanks! I like the idea, how you generate the dilationed region using ConvexHullRegion!
Unfortunately the Nintegrate gives me error messages:
(1) "Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small."
(2) "The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times" instead of decreasing."
I have tried increasing the number of points, but the integral does not seem to converge.

Comment: As I increase the number of random points of the spheres, these are the results with errors:
50 points: 0.266 + /- 0.061
100 points: 0.27 + /- 0.051
200 points: 0.282 + /- 0.064
500 points: 0.288 + /- 0.066
Is there any idea how to reduce errors?